# sed search and replace strings containing /

Tags: bash, sed

I am having trouble figuring out how to use `sed` to search and replace strings containing the `/` character in a text file `/etc/myconfig`.

For instance, in my existing text file, I have:

```
myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo
```

and I want this replaced by:

```
myparam /path/to/c argB=/path/to/D xo
```

I attempted doing this in bash:

```
line='myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo'
line_new='myparam /path/to/c argB=/path/to/D xo'
sed -i 's/$line/$line_new/g' /etc/myconfig
```

But nothing happens.

Attempting

```
grep -rn "$line" /etc/myconfig
```

does return me `'myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo'` though.

What's the correct way to express my `sed` command to execute this search and replace and correctly deal with the `/` command?  (I reckon that the `/` character in my strings are the ones giving me the problem because I used a similar `sed` command to search and replace another line in the text file with no problems and that line does not have a `/` character.

Comment: The substitution and quoting rules are really about bash rather than sed specifically. You might want to add bash as a tag.

Comment: ok. will add `bash` as a tag.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Don't escape the backslashes; you'll confuse yourself.  Use a different symbol after the `s` command that doesn't appear in the text (I'm using `%` in the example below):

```
line_old='myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo'
line_new='myparam /path/to/c argB=/path/to/D xo'
sed -i "s%$line_old%$line_new%g" /etc/myconfig
```

Also, enclose the whole string in double quotes; using single quotes means that `sed` sees `$line` (in the original) instead of the expanded value.  Inside single quotes, there is no expansion and there are no metacharacters.  If your text can contain almost any plain text character, use a control character (e.g. control-A or control-G) as the delimiter.

Note that the use of `-i` here mirrors what is in the question, but that assumes the use of GNU `sed`.  BSD `sed` (found on Mac OS X too) requires a suffix.  You can use `sed -i '' …` to replace in situ; that does not work with GNU `sed`.  To be portable between the two, use `-i.bak`; that will work with both — but gives you a backup file that you'll probably want to delete.  Other Unix platforms (e.g. AIX, HP-UX, Solaris) may have variants of `sed` that do not support `-i` at all.  It is not required by the POSIX specification for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Comment: thanks! The double quote `"` and the `%` did the trick.  I originally tried escaping the `/` character by doing `\/` and that did not work at all.

Comment: Note that if you need to specify a range of lines by regex and the regex contains slashes, you can use `sed -n '\@dir/file@,\@dir2/file2@p' where the backslash before the `@` indicates that the `@` is the search delimiter for this expression.

Comment: Note that one may need `sed -i -e`

Comment: @PhysicalChemist: Would you care to elaborate on your comment?  The `-e` is optional unless you'll have multiple expressions (`sed -e 's/a/b/' -b 's/xy/ZZ/g'`) — AFAIK.  Using `sed -i -e …` would make the script 'portable' between GNU `sed` and BSD `sed` at the cost of having BSD `sed` create a backup file with the extension `-e` (so if you edit file `data`, the backup file on Mac OS X will be `data-e`; GNU `sed` will not create a backup).  I'm not sure that's a good enough reason to do things that way; it would be better to use `-i.bak` and remove the backup — that works with both variants.

Comment: This is the only solution works for me

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work on my Ubuntu 18!

Comment: @Milan — Well, Ubuntu 18 is old, very old.  However, without seeing what you tried to execute, and what the error was, it is impossible to help you.  You could ask a new question, mentioning this one (with a URL to it) as where you got your ideas from, and then show what doesn't work.

Comment: TYPO ALERT: in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309968/sed-search-and-replace-strings-containing/10310050?noredirect=1#comment65323101_10310050) to PhysicalChemist, there is a `-b` that should be a `-e`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for such a quick response. I appreciate it. In my case, I ran the exact three lines you mentioned in your answer (of course, I created a temporary file containing `myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo` and mentioned that file in the command, instead of `/etc/config`). I didn't get any error but it also didn't replace the string i.e. the line remain unchanged!

Comment: @Milan: I created a script containing: `file_old="old.config";
file_new="new.config";
line_old='myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo';
line_new='myparam /path/to/c argB=/path/to/D xo';
echo "$line_old" > "$file_old";
sed -e "s%$line_old%$line_new%g" "$file_old" > "$file_new";
echo "== $file_old ==";
cat "$file_old";
echo "== $file_new ==";
cat "$file_new"` — Granted this doesn't use the `-i` option or scribble on a file in `/etc`, but the output was 4 lines `== old.config ==` — `myparam /path/to/a argB=/path/to/B xo` — `== new.config ==` — `myparam /path/to/c argB=/path/to/D xo`.

Comment: @Milan: If you can't get that to work, contact me via email (see my profile) and include detailed information, including the output from `sed --version`.  Include "Stack Overflow" in the subject and this question's URL in the body so I know who I'm talking to.

Answer (score 16):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i "s|$line|$line_new|g" /etc/myconfig
```

You must use `"`'s so that the `$line` and `$new_line` are interpolated. Also use `|` or any character not found in the match or replacement strings as a delimiter.

Comment: ok. I did not know about the `|` trick. So you mean to say that ANY delimiter will work as long as it is not a character found in the search or replace strings?

Comment: Yes; the first character after the `s` is used to separate the command into two parts; the pattern to be matched and the replacement pattern.  `s/search/replace/` uses `/` three times; but `s|search|replace|` or `s%search%replace%` works too.  Perl allows matching brackets (`s{search}{replace}`) but `sed` does not (unless, perhaps, you have activated the Perl patterns option if you have GNU `sed`).

Comment: Yes, within reason. `|` is a handy one to use as it is not likely to appear in a file. However it is a metacharacter (used in alternation) so if you wanted to say `s/this\|that/those/` then use another delimiter such as `@` or `#` or `,` or `?` or `%` etc. Also note this is for the substitution command for the search command `/.../` to use an alternative delimiter preceed the alternative with a backslash e.g. `\|foo|`

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler I don't think GNU sed has a `Perl patterns option` perhaps you are thinking of `ssed` (super sed) a fork of GNU sed.

Comment: It looks like you're right; it is GNU `grep` that has Perl regexes aboard, but not substitution operations.  That's the difficulty with these things, keeping track of which commands have which non-standard extensions.