# BASH: sed to remove "/" from a $STRING

Tags: string, bash, sed

First let me apologize for asking a question that:

- Has some examples, though I find them confusing
- Has a man page, also find confusing

**Problem:**

I would like to replace text in a $STRING within bash for a script I am writing. I chose to combine date/time to allow for easier end user integration.

```
STARTTIME="2015-03-17/11:30:00"
sed "Unknown"
```

**Attempted Solution:**

```
sed '/s// /' "$STARTTIME"
```

Desired result is to remove the "/" and end up with 2015-03-17 11:30:00 to then be passed to a command.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Maybe better this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309968/sed-search-and-replace-strings-containing

Comment: I don't see the similarity.

Comment: Your `sed` command was failing because you try to change `/` using `/` as delimiter. The suggested duplicate shows how to use another delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using bash, I would suggest that you used built-in [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
$ s='2015-03-17/11:30:00'
$ echo "${s/\// }"
2015-03-17 11:30:00
```

The syntax inside the braces means "replace the first occurrence of a forward slash (which needs escaping) with a space".