# Linux SED command syntax with escapes

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace a script call with a script call from a sub directory.

For example, originally I had `./output.sh` in my script to call the `output.sh` script in the current directory.

I want to replace `./output.sh` with `../output.sh` so that it calls `output.sh` in the parent directory.

I tried

```
sed -i -e 's/../\output.sh/./\output.sh/g' scriptName.sh
```

This returns with

> char 17: unknown option to 's'

Any help with the sed escape character syntax would be great.

Comment: To replace "./output.sh" with "../output.sh", you can try `sed 's@\([^.]\)\./output\.sh@\1../output.sh@g` (this won't match entries at the beginning of the line, but gives you a good start on a solution).  But this is not the correct way to solve your problem!

Comment: Or [sed search and replace strings containing /](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10309968/3266847) or [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5864146/3266847)

Answer (score 1):

Sed is bad at this; you'll risk turning an already existing `../output.sh` into `.../output.sh` if you're not careful.

This is the best sed can do:

```perl
sed -i 's@output\.sh@../$@g' scriptName.sh
```

(I'm using `@` in place of `/` so that there are no forward slashes to escape.  Sed accepts any punctuation character in place of forward slash.)

Note that this will convert `../output.sh` to `../../output.sh` but at least it doesn't create that triple-dot error.

Instead, try perl:

```perl
perl -pie 's@(?<!\.\./)(output\.sh\b)@../$1@g' scriptName.sh
```

This uses a negative look-behind to ensure it doesn't traverse to the parent's parent.  It also allows using `\b` to denote a word break just in case you have something like `output.shelf` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The slash character is special in sed's `s` command if you formulate it as `s/something/replacement/flags`, so the slashes in your file paths cause the error. Fortunately, you can use any other character right after `s`, for example `s@something@replacement@flags`. So, replacing the command with `s@\./output.sh@../output.sh@g` should do the trick.

Note two additional changes: you have to escape the dot in first expression since it's also a special character in regex and you also got reversed order of search expression and replacement (thanks charli for noticing this). You don't need the backslashes before `o` characters, either.

Alternatively, you can use `/` after `s` but escape the literal slashes you want to replace by preceding them with backslashes: `s/\.\/output.sh/..\/\output.sh/g`. It seems in your code you tried to use this solution but put the backslashes after instead of before the slashes.

Comment: If you don't escape the dots, it can replace strings as `directory/output.sh` to `director./output.sh`. Also, the question is to change from `./output.sh` to `../output.sh`, your patterns are reversed.

Comment: @charli Thanks for pointing this out. There were so many issues with the original expression I just skimmed over them without noticing.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick. Substitutes every appearance of `./output.sh` for `../output.sh` :

```
sed 's/\.\/output\.sh/\.\.\/output\.sh/g' scriptName.sh
```

The escape character is `\`. You should use it to escape:

- Every dot `.`. The dot is used as any character in regex.
- Every slash `/`. The slash character is used as delimiter between regex on the `s`command.