# Find and replace string with "/" recursively in a directories in RHEL 7.4

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed, redhat

I have to find and replace all the occurrence of a string in all files `/eOffice/eofficev6` to `/eOffice/SAPS/eofficev6` recursively in a directory in RHEL 7.4.

Problem is that I using `sed -i` but my string also containing `/` slash.

How to replace all string having `/`?

Comment: change `sed` subcommand delimiter `sed~/eOffice/eofficev6~/eOffice/SAPS/eofficev6~g`

Comment: This might help: [Escaping forward slashes in sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40715028/3776858)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed search and replace strings containing /](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10309968/608639), [How to replace strings containing slashes with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16790793/608639), [How to use different delimiters for sed substitute command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5864146/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
sed -i 's/\(\/eOffice\)\(\/eofficev6\)/\1\/SAPS\2/' input_file_name
```

The `"/eOffice"` and `"eofficev6"` parts are grouped and the `"SAPS"` is inserted in between.

For example, if the input is:

```
/eOffice/eofficev6
```

the output will be

```
/eOffice/SAPS/eofficev6
```

Forward slashes are escaped with `\`s.

Or without grouping just,

```
sed -i 's/\/eOffice\/eOfficev6/\/eOffice\/SAPS\/eOfficeb6/' input_file
```

Comment: I would be glad to identify my mistakes and learn. Any comments on why this answer is bad?

Comment: I think this answer is more than exaustive! I didn't know about groups [:
@ OP: You should flag this answer as the right one!

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to achieve what you want.

One: Escape slashes (E.G. `sed -i "s/\/eOffice\/eofficev6/\/eOffice\/SAPS\/eofficev6/" file`).

Two: change the delimiter (E.G. `sed -i "s|/eOffice/eofficev6|/eOffice/SAPS/eofficev6|" file`).