# Replacing "../../../" using sed

Tags: regex, sed, special-characters

I have a text file needs to edit. The first field contains the string

> "../../../"

and I want to replace with

> "/home"

. I tried using sed, but .. and / are special characters and I am a little bit stumbled how to match these patterns. I tried using something like (..), but it seems not working for my case. Could anyone help me understand how to match this kind of pattern?

Comment: Escape sequences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed search and replace strings containing /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309968/sed-search-and-replace-strings-containing)

Answer (score 2):

The `.` character is considered by sed as a wildcard, so it needs to be escaped. You will also need to escape the `/` character **if** you use it as a delimiter:

```
sed 's/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\//\/home/g'
#     ^                  ^      ^  <-- locations of '/' delimiters
#          ^^    ^^    ^^ ^^       <-- locations of '\/' to match literal '/' characters
```

The first character you provide to sed is used as the delimiter. If your regex looks like `/.../.../` or `s/.../.../` then the delimiter becomes `/`. If you replace that `/` delimiter with something else, then you don't need to escape the literal '/' character you're searching for (or replacing with):

```
# Same as above, but with delimiters swapped from '/' to '@':
sed 's@\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/@\/home@g'
#     ^                  ^      ^  <-- locations of '@' delimiters
#          ^^    ^^    ^^ ^^       <-- locations of '\/' to match literal '/' characters
```

Now with `@` used as the delimiters instead of `/`, you can simplify/rewrite that with fewer escaped `/` characters:

```
sed 's@\.\./\.\./\.\./@/home@g'
#     ^               ^     ^  <-- locations of '@' delimiters
#          ^    ^    ^ ^       <-- locations of literal '/' characters
```

**Note:**

Sadly, `\.` isn't very readable, but necessary so you don't have this kind of edge case:

```
$ echo 'ab/../cd/' | sed 's@../../../@/home@g'
/home
```

The above SHOULD be left unmodified:

```
$ echo 'ab/../cd/' | sed 's@\.\./\.\./\.\./@/home@g'
ab/../cd/
```

Comment: If you want to avoid backslashes entirely, you can stick the period in a single character grouping `[.]`  So, this: `sed 's#[.][.]/[.][.]/[.][.]#/home#'`  Still ugly.

Comment: A non-sed method could be to use `\Q` and `\E`: `perl -pe 's@(\Q../\E){3}@/home@g'` or `perl -pe 's@\Q../../../\E@/home@g'` so backslash and dot don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Slash `/` and dot `.` are both special regex characters to `sed`, so they need to be escaped if they are being used for their literal characters.
Dot is the single-character wildcard, so `..` matches *any two characters*, not just a literal two-dots.
Slash delimits the search, replace, and flags, as the *man page* for sed states `/regular expression/replacement/flags` -- so your search pattern has to escape both of those, making it

```
sed 's/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\./home/g' file > newfile
```

That gets pretty ugly, but sed can use something other than `/` as the delimiter. My favorite alternate is `~`, so the command would become

```
sed 's~\.\./\.\./\.\.~home~g' file > newfile
```

---

**Update**
Responding to @Gu Buddy's comment...

I don't know that it's "more elegant", but there are other ways to approach this.

The special characters such as `.` `*` `/` lose their special meaning when used in a character class, so `[.]` just means *period* not "any char", so you can avoid escaping them

```
sed 's/[.][.][/]/dot-dot-slash/g' file
sed 's/[.][.][/][.][.][/][.][.]/home/g' file
```

You can also use a match count (repetition) — a number or range in curly-braces, applied to the char or group preceding it — but those have to be escaped unless you use *extended regular expressions* ("ERE" vs basic regex "BRE"), enabled via the `-E` flag:

```
    sed 's~\([.][.][/]\)\{3\}~home/~' file  # with BRE
group start-^  grp end-^  ^-count
    sed -E 's~([.][.][/]){3}~home/~' file   # with ERE
    sed -E 's~([.]{2}[/]){3}~home/~' file   # also ERE
```

Notice in my original answer I avoided replacing the third slash, leaving it there to separate the replacement "home" from the remaining path...

```
../../../
        ^
```

...but using the repetition of `{3}` it will match and replace that third slash, so I have to include the slash after *home* in the replacement string.

I tested all of these on a file that just contains this:

```
../../../this/that/file.txt
../../../some/otherfile.txt
```

getting this output:

```
home/this/that/file.txt
home/some/otherfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I did figure it out eventually, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to write this rather than using escape on each special character, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes and dots:

```
sed 's/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\./\/home/g' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use regex to get the desired output.

```
echo "../../../" | sed -r 's/(..\/){3}/\/home/g'
```

**Option Detail**

According to `man page` of `sed`

*-E, -r, --regexp-extended*

use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).

**REGEX Details**

*(../){3}* : It will provide "../../../"

As we are using (/) in `sed` ex. sed 's///g' so we can not use normal (/) in sed so we need to escape this character by (/)

As this is to specific to (../) 3 times. If you want to change all (../) add * in place of {3}. ex. (../)*

/home : It gives "/home"

If you want one more (/) after home you can add (/home/)

sed -r 's/ `(../){3}` / `/home` /g'

So we are just substituting "/home" in place of "../../../". Now, you can change it as per your need.

Comment: That would incorrectly match `../ab/../` however. The `.`s must be escaped.

Comment: Why you want to match ../ab/../ with (../)3. What is your exact requirement??